# Is there fast algorithm to solve a puzzle

Tags: javascript, algorithm, puzzle

I have a puzzle to build some shape from pieces. I enumerate all places in the shape with numbers, then for each piece a compose a set of set of numbers, that this piece can take. So I have set A of set B of set C of natural numbers, for example,

```
[
  [ [1,3,5], [2,4,8], [1,5,9] ],
  [ [1,2,3,9], [3,5,19], [10,12,33], [14] ],
  ...
  [22,46,50], [13,15,33,44,57], ..., [7,17]
]
```

I need to select one set C from each set B so, that all numbers were unique and it will be solution for puzzle, for example,

```
[1,3,5] from first set,
[10,12,33] from second and so on,
where [1,3,5,10,12,33,..] <== contains unique numbers
```

Is there any algorithm (faster then brute force) to solve this task?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Language is javascript.

Answer (score 2):

It's NP-complete, as you might have expected. That doesn't mean it's hopeless (brute force sets a very low bar to beat), see below for an approach, it does mean that it is not expected that an algorithm exists that does it in polynomial time in the *worst case*. So you won't get a nice answer such as "do a bipartite matching" or something like that.

Anyway, it's NP-complete, in two steps:

## It's in NP

Fairly obvious, given a particular selection of "for each B, which set C is selected" (polynomial size) it's easy (polynomial time) to verify that a set C is picked from every B and that there is no overlap.

## It's NP-hard

There are going to be lots of ways to do it, but here's one example: reduce graph coloring to this problem.

For every vertex of the graph, make a set B. For every color k for every vertex i, make a set C(i,k) in B(i).

The idea is, if a particular set C(i,k) is picked in a set B(i), then that chooses the color k for vertex i, and we use the global "uniqueness" constraint to prevent an adjacent vertex from getting the same color. So:

In the set C(i,k) that corresponds to coloring B(i) with color k, add the number `pairToInt(i, k)`. To the set C(j,k) that corresponds to coloring B(j) with k (j adjacent to i in the input graph), also add that number. This bans coloring both i and j (adjacent) with the same color, because those sets C contain the same number and cannot be simultaneously selected. It does not ban non-adjacent vertexes from having the same color. `pairToInt` could be the Cantor Pairing Function or something simpler, doesn't matter as long as unique pairs map to unique integers.

---

For example you could use a SAT formulation:

- introduce a variable x[i] for every set C
- for every set B, make a clause that forces at least one of the sets in B to be selected
- for every pair of sets in C that share a number, make a clause that forces at most one of those sets to be selected

That's not too big, only quadratic size. By the way the solver might select multiple sets C for one B, but you can just discard the excess until only one C is selected per B. Discarding in that way wouldn't break the other constraints. This would be dangerous if there was a constraint that every number must be picked, but we don't have that constraint.

The question then is, is that faster than brute force? Practically it should be, for example a CDCL-based solver would quickly discover patterns of incompatible choices and avoid them in the future, and Boolean Constraint Propagation is used to quickly fill in the consequences of a decision rather than brute-forcing them too, so time is mostly spent on the hard "core" of a problem instance. Brute forcing would spend a lot of time on the easy parts as well.